# What is the setting "Evil Triangle" in Despotism 3k for?

Tags: despotism-3k

In the game Despotism 3k you play an evil AI enslaving humans. There is a setting "Evil Triangle". Does it do anything more than changing the background?
[image: settings]
[image: with triangle]
[image: without triangle]

Answer (score 1):

Nope, it doesn't do anything besides that.